# Returning a mutable reference that is behind an immutable reference, passed to the function

Tags: reference, rust, immutability, mutable

How is returning a mutable reference that is behind an immutable reference, passed as an argument to the function, handled?

```
struct Foo { i: i32 }

struct Bar<'b> {
    f: &'b mut Foo
}

impl<'a: 'b, 'b> Bar<'b> {
    fn func(&'a self) -> &'b mut Foo {
         self.f
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { i: 1 };

    let bar = Bar { f: &mut foo };
    bar.func(); 
}
```

gives the following error:

```
error[E0389]: cannot borrow data mutably in a `&` reference
 --> src/main.rs:9:14
  |
8 |         fn func(&'a self) -> &'b mut Foo {
  |                 -------- use `&'a mut self` here to make mutable
9 |              self.f
  |              ^^^^^^ assignment into an immutable reference
```

I (sort of) understand what the compiler is trying to prevent here. But I am confused with the error message `assignment into an immutable reference` . What exactly is being assigned into `self` (or inside of`self.f`?) ?

I wrote the following code to simulate this problem and got the same error message, which unlike the above one, I am able to understand. Here's the code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { i: 1 };

    let bar = Bar { f: &mut foo };
    let pbar = &bar;

    pbar.f.i = 2; // assignment into an immutable reference
}
```

In the first example,  is it trying to move the mutable reference `f` out of `self` (since `&mut` is not a `Copy` type), treating it as a mutation inside the immutable reference `self`, hence the error message `assignment into an immutable reference`?

Comment: If this were allowed, you could use two shared references to create two mutable references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create a mutable reference from an immutable one. This means that you need to change `&self` into `&mut self`:

```
impl<'a: 'b, 'b> Bar<'b> {
    fn func(&'a mut self) -> &'b mut Foo {
         self.f
    }
}
```

And now the your variable needs to be mutable so that you can take a mutable reference to it for the method:

```
let mut bar = Bar { f: &mut foo };
bar.func();
```

> What exactly is being assigned into self (or inside of `self.x`?) ?

The error message might be a little off. There is no assignment in your code, but you are returning a *mutable* reference. The only extra thing that a mutable reference would let you do here is to assign `self.f` or `self.f.i`.

Definitely this error message can be improved, but it does include a hint to make the `&'a self` mutable to fix the problem.

Now, your original question:

> How is returning a mutable reference that is behind an immutable reference, passed as an argument to the function, handled?

Rust provides a variety of container types for interior mutability, such as `Cell` and `RefCell`. These types take the responsibility for ensuring correctness away from the compiler and make it a runtime check. One way of applying a `RefCell` to your code might be like this:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::ops::DerefMut;

struct Foo { i: i32 }

struct Bar<'b> {
    // store the data in a RefCell for interior mutability
    f: &'b RefCell<Foo>
}

impl<'a: 'b, 'b> Bar<'b> {
    // Return a RefMut smart pointer instead of mutable ref, but hide the implementation,
    // just exposing it as something that can be mutably dereferenced as a Foo
    fn func(&'a self) -> impl DerefMut<Target = Foo> + 'b {
         self.f.borrow_mut()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = RefCell::new(Foo { i: 1 });
    let bar = Bar { f: &foo };

    let mut f = bar.func(); 
    f.i = 3;
}
```