# Why can I not return a mutable reference to an outer variable from a closure?

Tags: reference, rust, closures, lifetime, mutable

I was playing around with Rust closures when I hit this interesting scenario:

```
fn main() {
    let mut y = 10;

    let f = || &mut y;

    f();
}
```

This gives an error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
4 |     let f = || &mut y;
  |                ^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime  as defined on the body at 4:13...
 --> src/main.rs:4:13
  |
4 |     let f = || &mut y;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that closure can access `y`
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
4 |     let f = || &mut y;
  |                ^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the call at 6:5...
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     f();
  |     ^^^
note: ...so type `&mut i32` of expression is valid during the expression
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     f();
  |     ^^^
```

Even though the compiler is trying to explain it line by line, I still haven't understood what exactly it is complaining about.

Is it trying to say that the mutable reference cannot outlive the enclosing closure?

The compiler does not complain if I remove the call `f()`.

Comment: Could this be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197812/returning-a-mutable-reference-that-is-behind-an-immutable-reference-passed-to-t) in some way, as I understand that closures are basically a form of `struct` without a definite type?

Comment: As a workaround, you can take the reference in the outer function and return that from the closure ([playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=0042c242ba32636325f43a3260d364a5&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)), but I don't know why your original code fails…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Short version

The closure `f` stores a mutable reference to `y`.  If it were allowed to return a copy of this reference, you would end up with two simultaneous mutable references to `y` (one in the closure, one returned), which is forbidden by Rust's memory safety rules.

#### Long version

The closure can be thought of as

```
struct __Closure<'a> {
    y: &'a mut i32,
}
```

Since it contains a mutable reference, the closure is called as `FnMut`, essentially with the definition

```
fn call_mut(&mut self, args: ()) -> &'a mut i32 { self.y }
```

Since we only have a mutable reference to the closure itself, we can't move the field `y` out, neither are we able to copy it, since mutable references aren't `Copy`.

We can trick the compiler into accepting the code by forcing the closure to be called as `FnOnce` instead of `FnMut`.  This code works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let x = String::new();
    let mut y: u32 = 10;
    let f = || {
        drop(x);
        &mut y
    };
    f();
}
```

Since we are consuming `x` inside the scope of the closure and `x` is not `Copy`, the compiler detects that the closure can only be `FnOnce`.  Calling an `FnOnce` closure passes the closure itself by value, so we are allowed to move the mutable reference out.

Another more explicit way to force the closure to be `FnOnce` is to pass it to a generic function with a trait bound.  This code works fine as well:

```
fn make_fn_once<'a, T, F: FnOnce() -> T>(f: F) -> F {
    f
}

fn main() {
    let mut y: u32 = 10;
    let f = make_fn_once(|| {
        &mut y
    });
    f();
}
```

Comment: Moving-out-of-borrowed-context is more easy to understand than lifetimes-conflict. I hope both these are related to each other and that the lifetimes-conflict stems out from  moving-out-of-borrowed-context issue, which I believe  is the core issue.

Comment: They are not related. Lifetime relates to memory region validity (a pointer must point to a valid memory slot) whereas 
moving-out-of-borrowed context relates to memory aliasing (two ipothetical "writable" pointers pointing to the same memory slot: you cannot have two owners in rust).
I don't know which of them are more easy to understand, both of them are core concepts to understand and both came into play here.

Answer (score 10):

There are two main things at play here:

1. Closures cannot return references to their environment
2. A mutable reference to a mutable reference can only use the lifetime of the outer reference (unlike with immutable references)

---

#### Closures returning references to environment

**Closures cannot return any references with the lifetime of `self`** (the closure object). Why is that? Every closure can be called as `FnOnce`, since that's the super-trait of `FnMut` which in turn is the super-trait of `Fn`. `FnOnce` has this method:

```
fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
```

Note that `self` is passed by value. So since `self` is consumed (and now lives within the `call_once` function`) we cannot return references to it -- that would be equivalent to returning references to a local function variable.

In theory, the `call_mut` would allow to return references to `self` (since it receives `&mut self`). But since `call_once`, `call_mut` and `call` are all implemented with the same body, closures in general cannot return references to `self` (that is: to their captured environment).

Just to be sure: closures can capture references and return those! And they can capture *by* reference and return that reference. Those things are something different. It's just about what is stored in the closure type. If there is a reference stored within the type, it can be returned. But we can't return references to anything stored within the closure type.

#### Nested mutable references

Consider this function (note that the argument type implies `'inner: 'outer`; `'outer` being shorter than `'inner`):

```
fn foo<'outer, 'inner>(x: &'outer mut &'inner mut i32) -> &'inner mut i32 {
    *x
}
```

This won't compile. On the first glance, it seems like it should compile, since we're just peeling one layer of references. And it does work for immutable references! But mutable references are different here to preserve soundness.

It's OK to return `&'outer mut i32`, though. But it's impossible to get a direct reference with the longer (inner) lifetime.

#### Manually writing the closure

Let's try to hand code the closure you were trying to write:

```
let mut y = 10;

struct Foo<'a>(&'a mut i32);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn call<'s>(&'s mut self) -> &'??? mut i32 { self.0 }
}

let mut f = Foo(&mut y);
f.call();
```

What lifetime should the returned reference have?

- It can't be `'a`, because we basically have a `&'s mut &'a mut i32`. And as discussed above, in such a nested mutable reference situation, we can't extract the longer lifetime!
- But it also can't be `'s` since that would mean the closure returns something with the lifetime of `'self` ("borrowed from `self`"). And as discussed above, closures can't do that.

So the compiler can't generate the closure impls for us.

Comment: [`Fn` closures _can_ return a reference to a captured variable.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bd760f703f48e6e6b0c0094c8694a9a8&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)  According to your argument, this should be impossible, yet it works.

Comment: @SvenMarnach In your example, `y` is captured by reference. So in the closure's `self` a `&i32` is stored. So the closure isn't returning a reference to self, but captures the environment by reference and returns that. That's what I meant by the last paragraph in the closure part. But I know, it's complicated :/ Try ` move || { &y }` instead and you will get an error. I might try to improve my explanation.

Comment: In the original example, `y` is also captured by (mutable) reference, and the closure isn't returning a reference to `self`.  Just remove all `mut`s from your argument, and you get an argument that the case I mentioned should be impossible.

Comment: I think the actual reason is that a mutable reference isn't `Copy`, while an immutable reference is, and we can't move the mutable reference out of the borrowed context.  That's not what the error message says, though.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Correct, if we use immutable references, it works. The problem only arises due to the interplay of the both things I mention. The nested reference thing (which only applies to mutable references) basically forced the closure to return something with the lifetime of `self`, but since that's not possible, the error occurs.

Comment: Even if the `FnMut` trait was defined to return `&'s mut Output`, you still wouldn't be able to move the mutable reference stored in the closure out of the borrowed context.  The lifetimes just don't seem to be relevant here, even if the error message says so.  (For what it's worth, the error message has already been fixed in the NLL version of the borrow checker.)

Comment: *In theory, the signature of `call_mut` would allow to return references to `self`*: I don't think so, `call_mut` is `fn call_mut(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output`. In order to return a self-reference, `Output` would have to have a lifetime parameter. (Which isn't possible without GATs.) I think this explains why it's not possible to return a reference to `self` without needing to go into the relationship between `FnMut` and `FnOnce` (although you raise a good point about how `FnMut` probably can't be "fixed" once GATs arrive).

Comment: @trentcl Oh yep, right. That formulation is a bit misleading. I meant: since `call_mut` receives `&mut self`, we could in theory use the `self` lifetime to return something. But yeah, the return type or associated type would need to change, true.

Comment: All three answers are great and together they summarize everything.! Sven Marnach's answer talks about moving-out-of-borrowed-context issue  , attdona gave a very good insight on how compiler treats the code (lifetime followed by borrowck analysis).  Lukas Kalbertodt's gave a a very good description on the interplay between lifetime and borrowck.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: I know this thread was a while back but I'm having the same problem here and don't quite understand the **Nested mutable references** part. Can you explain it a bit more in details please ? Why it doesn't work for mutable ref, what is the soundness that you were talking about ?

Comment: @Quoc-HaoTran For example, if that were to work, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b826ee6a7be147d08dd676d47a91f61d) would compile. And as you can see, that would be UB. Another way to think about this is that `&mut T` is *not* `Copy` nor `Clone`. If the `foo` function in my answer would compile, then we could circumvent this restriction. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Ah I see ! Thanks for the example !

Answer (score 9):

Consider this code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut y: u32 = 10;

    let ry = &mut y;
    let f = || ry;

    f();
}
```

It works because the compiler is able to infer `ry`'s lifetime: the reference `ry` lives in the same scope of `y`.

Now, the equivalent version of your code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut y: u32 = 10;

    let f = || {
        let ry = &mut y;
        ry
    };

    f();
}
```

Now the compiler assigns to `ry` a lifetime associated to the scope of the closure body, not to the lifetime associated with the main body.

Also note that the immutable reference case works:

```
fn main() {
    let mut y: u32 = 10;

    let f = || {
        let ry = &y;
        ry
    };

    f();
}
```

This is because `&T` has copy semantics and `&mut T` has move semantics, see  [Copy/move semantics documentation of &T/&mut T types itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381212/copy-move-semantics-documentation-of-t-mut-t-types-itself) for more details.

### The missing piece

The compiler throws an error related to a lifetime:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
```

but as pointed out by Sven Marnach there is also a problem related to the error

```
cannot move out of borrowed content
```

But why doesn't the compiler throw this error?

The short answer is that the compiler first executes type checking and then borrow checking.

#### the long answer

A closure is made up of two pieces:

- the **state** of the closure: a struct containing all the variables captured by the closure
- the **logic** of the closure: an implementation of the `FnOnce`, `FnMut` or `Fn` trait

In this case the state of the closure is the mutable reference `y` and the logic is the body of the closure `{ &mut y }` that simply returns a mutable reference.

When a reference is encountered, Rust controls two aspects:

1. the **state**: if the reference points to a valid memory slice, (i.e. the read-only part of lifetime validity);
2. the **logic**: if the memory slice is aliased, in other words if it is pointed from more than one reference simultaneously;

Note the move out from borrowed content is forbidden for avoiding memory aliasing.

The Rust compiler executes its job through [several stages](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rustc-guide/high-level-overview.html#the-main-stages-of-compilation), here's a simplified workflow:

```
.rs input -> AST -> HIR -> HIR postprocessing -> MIR -> HIR postprocessing -> LLVM IR -> binary
```

The compiler reports a lifetime problem because it first executes the type checking phase in `HIR postprocessing` (which comprises lifetime analysis) and after that, if successful, executes borrow checking in the `MIR postprocessing` phase.