# Why this rust FnMut closure code has lifetime errors?

Tags: rust

I want to make a closure hold `&mut Vec`, but these simple few lines of code can't compile.

I know this can be solved with `RefCell`, I just can't figure the error out.

```
struct Server<'a> {
    data: &'a mut Vec<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut c = || {
         Server{
            data: &mut data,
        }
    };
    let server = c();
}
```

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=60171de3b0ee495af643e0d25afc7ac1)

The error message is:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:36:19
   |
36 |             data: &mut data,
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime '_ as defined on the body at 34:17...
  --> src/main.rs:34:17
   |
34 |     let mut c = || {
   |                 ^^
note: ...so that closure can access `data`
  --> src/main.rs:36:19
   |
36 |             data: &mut data,
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the call at 39:18...
  --> src/main.rs:39:18
   |
39 |     let server = c();
   |                  ^^^
note: ...so type `Server<'_>` of expression is valid during the expression
  --> src/main.rs:39:18
   |
39 |     let server = c();
   |                  ^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

**Update:**

I found [this post](http://blog.luxko.site/post/closure-lifetime-hrt/) answered the question, but I could not understand some parts of it:

> It turns out that, returning &`'a mut i32` is not feasible for the shorter-live invocation of `call_mut`. What we’ve really wanted for the return type of `call_mut`, was something like:

```
impl<'a> FnMut<(usize,)> for Closure<'a> {
    extern "rust-call"
    fn<'b> call_mut(&'b mut self, (i,): (usize, )) -> &'b mut i32 {
        self.inner.get_mut(i).unwrap()
    }
}
```

1. Why the `call_mut` fn has to use a `'b` lifetime instead of `'a`?
2. I found the code would work if change `data: &mut Vec<i32>` to `data: &Vec<i32>`, which makes me more confused that why lifetime is related to `mut`?

Comment: 1. is answered by [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29401626/3650362) (the answers suggest ways to fix it); 2. is related to [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/3650362), but I'm not sure exactly why the compiler doesn't like this. I tried making it a `move` closure and taking the reference outside the closure to no effect, which makes me think I might be missing the point.

Comment: This question was [cross-posted to users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-this-rust-fnmut-closure-code-has-lifetime-errors/33063).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I not return a mutable reference to an outer variable from a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752259/why-can-i-not-return-a-mutable-reference-to-an-outer-variable-from-a-closure)